# How to highlight the clicked navigation item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a navigation bar:

```
<div id="the navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want it so that when the user clicks on any of the items, it becomes highlighted (for example, it should get a red background). If a different item is clicked, then the currently highlighted one should no longer be highlighted and the one that was just clicked should be. There should only be one lit at any given time.

How do I do this with jQuery?

Comment: You should really post what you've tried and any relative source code.

Comment: Ive tried both below and it didnt work. Updated my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Updated to use the actual HTML you have now posted.  First, I had to remove the space your your id value as a space makes it difficult or impossible to use it in many selectors.

```
<div id="thenavigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd suggest this CSS:

```
.highlight {background-color: red;}
```

to go with this jQuery:

```
$('#thenavigation li a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    return(false);   // no default behavior from clicking on the link
});
```

You can see it work here with your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r9s7w/.

Or working here without the `<a>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TreKN/.

Comment: Does not look like this worked due to hyperlinks in li. Updated post with my code.

Comment: @Teiviere - I modified my code to work with your actual HTML.  Note: I removed the space from your id as that makes problems for selectors.

Comment: @Teiviere - FYI, you probably don't need to use an `<a>` inside your `<li>` if you're not using the href value of the link.  You can capture clicks on the li directly in javascript.

Comment: I would like the hand to show up when the user mouses over (the cursor). Hm, I tried it and for some reason it does not work. The div I have with that navigation is hidden and is shown after a user clicks on some other button.

Comment: Did you fix the id to be "thenavigation" without any spaces?  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r9s7w/

Comment: When you talked about getting rid of the a href, is there a way to get the mouse cursor to show as a hand?

Comment: @Teiviere - You can make the mouse cursor show as a hand with this CSS: `#thenavigation li:hover {cursor: pointer;}`.  See a working example without the `<a>` tags here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TreKN/

Comment: This works for static page.. When the page reload, the highlight vanishes!!! i mean, visiting a new link

Comment: @madhairsilence - javascript changes to a page are for the current page session only.  If you want the state to be persistent for future pages or page loads, you have to store it somewhere (either on your server or on the client (cookie or local storage).

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click handler that assings a class name to the current element and removes the same class name from other elements in the list:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then style the active link using css.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/zzlawlzz/MtTBQ/

```
$('#myNavbar li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').children('li').css('color','gray');
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Like Tatu Ulmanen said, use the :active css pseudo elements for css